# error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git

I am getting the error failed to push some refs, below

```
$ git push origin bob
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git:/var/git/webservices.git
 * [new branch]      bob -> bob
error: failed to push some refs to 'git:/var/git/webservices.git'
```

Note: this has **nothing to do with non-fast-forward** pushes.

To try and rule it out I have set 777 permissions to the whole remote repo.

Any idea how to find what ref it can't push?

(to be clear it has pushed the new branch to the repo and this is a repo that was previously working fine)

Comment: I'd wager it's the first it tries, for a reason as simple as insufficient permissions on target repository.

Comment: you could also try doing a local push (both on your client machine and on the server) instead of using ssh

Comment: Second chance: disk full or quota exceeded?

Comment: plenty of space on all mounts, and other repos on the same box working fine

Comment: You only pushed one ref, `bob`.  The weird thing is that it looks like it succeeded, and then it says it failed after all (?!).  If you log in to the server, is the ref there?  (cd to the bare repo and run `git rev-parse bob` to see.)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to work out what other refs it might push as well, eg. HEAD but that is there too.

Comment: @torek thanks, your comment reassured my thinking, and helped me find the answer

Answer (score 2):

Our problem was that setting 777 permissions to the repo added execute permissions and activated the sample hooks!

When this repo was created they did not use to have the .sample on the end.  Very dangerous. :(

Comment: Setting chmod 0777 on everything is *always* very dangerous. Unless you know exactly that you want the files to be executable, don’t give them 0777 but 0666 instead. But in general, to not make executable files un-executable by accident, use `chmod a+rw` instead.

Comment: I agree, I only resorted to that because a+rw did not solve our original permissions problem that led to this one.